# Node js + Objection js + Postgresql. Argument of type '{ token: string }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PartialUpdate<User>'

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, knex.js, objection.js

**Environment:**

1. node js
2. ES6
3. knex: ^0.16.3
4. objection: ^1.5.3
5. pg: ^7.8.0 *~ postgresql*

**Problem:**

I can't update user token in the database. I get an error message from typescript.

**Typescript error message:**

> Argument of type '{ token: string; }' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'PartialUpdate<User>'. Object literal may only specify known
>   properties, and 'token' does not exist in type 'PartialUpdate<User>'.

**Problem method**

If I write `@ts-ignore`, the method will work, but I can't understand.

Why does it give me an error?

```
import { User } from '@database/models';

...
const setToken = async (id: any, token: string) => {
  try {
    await transaction(User.knex(), trx =>
      User.query(trx)
      // An error appears on this line
        .update({ token })
        .where({ id }),
    );
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};
```

**My user model**

```
'use strict';

import { Model } from 'objection';

export default class User extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return 'users';
  }

  static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: 'object',

      properties: {
        id: { type: 'uuid' },
        full_name: { type: 'string', minLength: 1, maxLength: 255 },
        email: { type: 'string', minLength: 1, maxLength: 255 },
        avatar: { type: 'string' },
        provider_data: {
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            uid: { type: 'string' },
            provider: { type: 'string' },
          },
        },
        token: { type: 'string' },
        created_at: { type: 'timestamp' },
        updated_at: { type: 'timestamp' },
      },
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) Please don't use blockquotes for emphasis, use them for quotes. (No emphasis is needed regardless.)

Comment: What line of your code is TypeScript giving you that error on?

Comment: The error is about a call to a function where you're passing an object with a `token` string property into a function expecting `PartialUpdate<User>`. None of your code shows a function with a parameter typed `PartialUpdate<User>`. Please reduce the problem to a [mcve] and post that. We need to see the function being called, and the call to it.

Comment: The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I did not define the types of variables in my model. An example from the official library that gave me know about what I did wrong -  https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/tree/master/examples/express-ts

**Updated model**

```
export default class User extends Model {
  readonly id!: v4;
  full_name?: string;
  email?: string;
  avatar?: string;
  provider_data?: {
    uid: string;
    provider: string;
  };
  token?: string;

  static tableName = 'users';

  static jsonSchema = {
    type: 'object',

    properties: {
      id: { type: 'uuid' },
      full_name: { type: 'string', minLength: 1, maxLength: 255 },
      email: { type: 'string', minLength: 1, maxLength: 255 },
      avatar: { type: 'string' },
      provider_data: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          uid: { type: 'string' },
          provider: { type: 'string' },
        },
      },
      token: { type: 'string' },
      created_at: { type: 'timestamp' },
      updated_at: { type: 'timestamp' },
    },
  };
}
```

**Updated method**

```
const setToken = async (id: any, token: string) => {
  try {
    User.query()
      .update({ token })
      .where({ id });
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**please provide code with variable partialUpdate. because you are having an error because of the wrong declaration of the type of variable partialUpdate. TypeScript fully focused on variable Type and if the Type of the variable does not match the content you are providing to that variable type error generates. you are passing object type value {token:string} to your variable partialUpdate which can only hold string type variable when you declared it. **

```
PartialUpdate:Object
```

or

```
PartialUpdate = {}
```

will solve the problem.